# How to apply multiple tags to a test case in pytest?

Tags: tags, pytest, tagging, markers

In [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/) you can mark a test case with a tag.

```
@pytest.mark.windows
def test_will_fail():
    assert False
```

Now above test case is marked with the tag 'windows'. Running pytest with `pytest -m windows` will execute only test cases which are marked with the tag 'windows'.

But what if I want to apply more than one tag? e.g. I would like to tag above test case with 'windows' and 'smoke'. How would I do that? (I haven't seen an example on that in pytest docs.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are simply [Python decorators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Decorators) which you can stack:

```
@pytest.mark.smoke
@pytest.mark.windows
def test_will_fail():
    assert False
```